# how to clear listview and add the new listview

Tags: java, android, listview

If I clear the list view, the listview will gone.The list view will fetch data from the for loop.

**Workarounds:**

- Putting  setdaylist.clear() inside the any loop will clear the all listview and display only one list item.
- Setting it at the top of method will erase all the listview, any solution?

**Code:**

```
 public void onDataGotOnline(JSONObject response) {

    DateTime today = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        JSONArray currentData = response.getJSONArray("list");
               // setdaylist.clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            DateTime tomorow = today.plusDays(i).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
            String dtStr = fmt.print(tomorow);
            int info = 0;


            for(; info<currentData.length();info++ ){
                JSONObject managedata = currentData.getJSONObject(info);
                String time= managedata.getString("dt_txt");

                if(time.equals(dtStr)){

                    int getResult=info+8;

                    double[] arrayAverageTemp = new double[8];
                    double[] arrayMaxTemp = new double[8];
                    double[] arrayMinTemp = new double[8];
                    int[] arrayWheaterId = new int[8];

                    for (int a = info; a < getResult; a++) {
                        JSONObject datalist = currentData.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray weatherdata = datalist.getJSONArray("weather");
                        JSONObject weatherdata2 = weatherdata.getJSONObject(weatherdata.length() - 1);
                        int id = weatherdata2.getInt("id");

                        JSONObject weather = datalist.getJSONObject("main");
                        double avg_temp = weather.getDouble("temp");
                        double max_temp = weather.getDouble("temp_max");
                        double min_temp = weather.getDouble("temp_min");


                        arrayWheaterId[a-info]=id;
                        arrayAverageTemp[a-info]=avg_temp;
                        arrayMaxTemp[a-info]=max_temp;
                        arrayMinTemp[a-info]=min_temp;
                    }


                    ManageData manageData = new ManageData();
                    double max = manageData.findMax(arrayMaxTemp);
                    double min = manageData.findMin(arrayMinTemp);
                    WheatherData day = new WheatherData();
                    day.setDay("sunday");
                   // int image = convert.covertImage(icon);
                    day.setImage(R.drawable.ic_image_01d);
                    day.setDescrption("asdasd");
                    day.setAvgTemp("14 °c");
                    day.setMaxTemp(max+ "°c");
                    day.setMinTemp(min+ "°c");

                    setdaylist.add(day);


                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //  findMax(arrayMaxTemp);
                    //findMin(arrayMinTemp);
                    //findID(arrayWheaterId);
                    //findaverage(arrayAverageTemp);





                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e){

    }

}
```

Comment: When do you want to clear a listview ? When do you want to create a new listview?

Comment: Use `setdaylist.clear();` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` now add data to the list and call notify again

Comment: @09Q71AO534 the above method onDatagotOnline is inteface method, when that method is called the old listview should be gone and new listitem should be added

Comment: try placing the `setdaylist.clear();` above the for loop.

Comment: @SaravInfern, tired it and only one listitem is shown.

Comment: Is `setdaylist` defined globally? Then try to create a new list above the loop and then add the items to the new list.

Comment: thank you guys its fixed now. :)

Comment: :) Post the fix that worked - which would help others.

Comment: its embarrassed to say but i got android studio caching problem, adding setdaylist.clear() before loop works, problem was my previous code was running because of cache, cleaning project and building it again fix it all, sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion above.

- Issue was due to the caching problem in Android studio.
- Cleaning Project and Building it removes the existing cache.

By which the `setdaylist` before the for loop shown below works as expected.

```
public void onDataGotOnline(JSONObject response) {
        ...
        try {
            ...
            setdaylist.clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                ...  
                for(; info<currentData.length();info++ ){
                    ...
                    if(time.equals(dtStr)){
                        ...
                           setdaylist.add(day);
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){}
    }
```